# Assignment problem in a subscription system

Tags: sorting, set

I'm working on subscription system and I need to have the output data processed to register the subscribers correctly and automatically.

I work mainly with PHP/Mysql but it's not a PHP/Mysql problem but rather a data sorting problem.

My data have two sets :

```
"topics"=> [
    "Women rights"=> ["capacity"=>3]
    "Chelter"=> ["capacity"=>5]
    "Charity"=> ["capacity"=>7]
    "Training"=> ["capacity"=>17]
    "Child care"=> ["capacity"=>13]
    "Nursing"=> ["capacity"=>8]
    "Garbage collection"=> ["capacity"=>2]
    "Managing"=> ["capacity"=>1]
]
"applications"= [
    "Alan"=>[
        ["topic"=>"Charity",            "priority"=>1, "rankInTopic"=>1],
        ["topic"=>"Chelter",            "priority"=>2, "rankInTopic"=>3],
        ["topic"=>"Garbage collection", "priority"=>3, "rankInTopic"=>1],
        ["topic"=>"Managing",           "priority"=>4, "rankInTopic"=>12]
        ]
    "David"=>[
        ["topic"=>"Women rights",       "priority"=>4, "rankInTopic"=>2],
        ["topic"=>"Chelter",            "priority"=>3, "rankInTopic"=>2],
        ["topic"=>"Garbage collection", "priority"=>1, "rankInTopic"=>3],
        ["topic"=>"Managing",           "priority"=>2, "rankInTopic"=>9]
        ["topic"=>"Nursing",            "priority"=>5, "rankInTopic"=>3]
        ["topic"=>"Charity",            "priority"=>6, "rankInTopic"=>3]
        ]
    "Sonia"=>[
        ["topic"=>"Chelter",            "priority"=>2, "rankInTopic"=>1],
        ["topic"=>"Training",           "priority"=>1, "rankInTopic"=>5]
        ]
    "Robert"=>[
        ["topic"=>"Garbage collection", "priority"=>6, "rankInTopic"=>2],
        ["topic"=>"Child care",         "priority"=>3, "rankInTopic"=>2],
        ["topic"=>"Women rights",       "priority"=>1, "rankInTopic"=>1],
        ["topic"=>"Managing",           "priority"=>2, "rankInTopic"=>4]
        ["topic"=>"Nursing",            "priority"=>5, "rankInTopic"=>1]
        ["topic"=>"Charity",            "priority"=>4, "rankInTopic"=>5]
        ]
    "Diana"=>[
        ["topic"=>"Child care",         "priority"=>1, "rankInTopic"=>1]
        ]
    ]
```

I would like to subscribe each applicant in one topic only .
Topics are aordered by "rankInTopic" field then by "priority" field.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The term for what you're trying to do is **matching** rather than ranking or sorting.

This problem can be expressed as a weighted bipartite matching. Sometimes this is also called the "assignment problem."

The data structure is an undirected bipartite graph with edge weights - often though not necessarily represented as a matrix of weights.  One set of vertices will be "seats" in the topic areas.  One vertex per unit of capacity. The other set will be applicants.  Each applicant preference is an edge to each of the respective seats. The weight of the edge is a single integer. To accommodate both priority and rank, you'll need the lexicographic order expressed in a single number.  Something sufficiently big, e.g. `rankInTopic * sum(all priorities) + priority` will work.

Now a standard weighted bipartite matching algorithm will pick edges that pair each applicant with exactly one seat.  The set of edges it picks will have a the minimum possible sum.  (Some implementations are wired to find the maximum. Then you'll want to negate the edge weights.)

The [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) is the classical solution. Iirc, a good implementation is O(n^3) in the number of vertices.  You could look for a library or implement it yourself. It's not trivial, but not terrible either.

I actually used this algorithm to match students with desired courses in an academic setting. It worked well. I added some parameters to use weights more sophisticated than consecutive preferences.  E.g. if I wanted to favor giving a maximum number of students their first preference by causing others to get less desirable assignments, I could try weights something like 1,5,6,7... for priorities 1,2,3,4...  Or if I wanted to cause all students to get something in their top 3, I'd use something like 1,2,3,10,....  It was great to be able to explain the algorithm and say with perfect confidence that the assignment was optimal.

**Edit**

You found an implementation that requires a square matrix as input. This is less efficient than one that allows rectangles, but still ought to be fine. So it handles N things to be matched with N other things.  I.e. the matching will be perfect.

Let the columns of the matrix be the seats in these topics. So the first three will be for "Women's Rights", the next 5 will be "Chelter", etc.  Looks like 54 in all.

The rows will be people. There are only 5, so what to do with the other 49? Fill these in with very high equal weights. I think 1e6 will work. The algorithm will be sure to use the much lower weighted edges based on priority first. These will all connect to "real" people. The 49 "pseudo people" will be matched last with unused topic seats. Those matches will be meaningless and ignored.

For the weight in position [person P, seat in Topic T], use (priority * 10000 + rankInTopic), where priority and rank are what P has for T. If P has expressed no preference for T, then use a huge number  meaning "infinity". Something like a million ought to work.

Pass this to the algorithm. The return value should be an array with 54 elements.  The first five rows will show which seat each person has been matched with. From those you can determine which topic they're in. The rest will contain matches with arbitrary unused seats.

PHP is a poor-performing environment for this kind of problem (unless you're compiling to native code somehow, and even then). Also this implementation is going to waste memory and time computing matches that aren't needed. The Java implementation mentioned in the Wikipedia page accepts a rectangular array, so is more suitable for this task. It would probably take a couple of careful hours to transcribe the Java to PHP.

Comment: I'm not a math guy, so I'm still in the same point. I can calculate the matrix and I found an implementation in PHP of the Hungarian Algorithm:
https://github.com/rpfk/Hungarian/
I'm trying to use it without success.

Comment: Hi. I added some implementation notes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gene, you are very helpful.
In fact, I was mistaken. I used the rank witch is based on calculated scores. There is some duplicates in these scores and preferences.
I don't know if a solution in three dimensions exists.
I solved the problem the old way by incrementing all choices filling the seats by score in topic and preference then discarding unfulfilled preferences and filled topics.

Comment: Hi Gene,
I found this implementation in php that can process rectangle matrix.
I'd like to use it.
The most important parameter in this assignment problem is that the persons are assigned to topic firstly by a numerical value of a decimal 100 based score in each topic then by preference (1 to 10).
The final result will ideally to have each topic seats filled within that order.
A very big Thank you.
https://github.com/SarahJehin/php-munkres

Comment: Hi,
I missed the most advanced solution in PHP to this assignment problem.
I found this implementation of the Hungarian Algorithm in Packagist that can be used strait away.
https://packagist.org/packages/kick-in/hungarian.
The problem is that the set of data I user have a lot of "Topics" with a lot of seats (1046 in total) and over 10000 applications.
Even with a subset of data, it takes a lot of time to build the matrix then process the results.
I just have to balance the weight in position.

Comment: Yes an O(n^3) algorithm - which this is - has run time that ramps up quickly. 2x more data means 8x more run time more-or-less. PHP as I said is a bad environment. I was solving problems with 1,500 seats and students in about 3 seconds on a 1999 Pentium (x86) with the implementation in C.  Also you need a version that allows the input matrix to be rectangular. That will save about 10x in data size for your particular problem. Your problem should be doable in a few seconds. I'm glad you're getting closer to a solution.